# How to suppress the Delete From All Devices confirmation in the Photos app?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I installed Yosemite 10.10.3, which comes with the new Photos app. Seems nice so far...

When deleting a photo on my MacBook, a warning message is shown:

[image: Delete from All Devices — This photo will be deleted from all your devices.]

I don't need to see this every time I delete a photo. I can't see any settings to suppress this message - are there any known workarounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Command+Delete avoids the confirmation dialog.

Comment: That is much less painful, thank you. I was hoping for some random .plist somewhere that had "ConfirmPhotoDelete" or something...

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the photo or photos using the right-click context menu rather than the keyboard shortcut then this confirmation sheet is not shown.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as of OSX 10.10.3 I'm finding that the right-click context menu's Delete also shows the delete confirmation message